# Ajax Live Text Box Pushed Down all Html Elemant

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

I used [Ajax Live search](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) from `xml` file in my site.

Search textbox located in navigation bar but when i typed something and get results the area of nav bar being extent and push down all body element.

Can you help me about this issue my code given in the below.

```
<div class="col-sm-2" style="width:270px;">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Arama" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                <div id="livesearch"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I didn't assigned any css yet.

`#livesearch` is the function of php. I didn't put to whole navigation bar because it's very long.. but this search bar one of the nav bar element and used bootstrap codes in it.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the `css` also?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp i used exactly same code which in the link. I didn't apply any css to search box i would like to what setting should i add in new class for the searchbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem**

The `Live Search` append a `div` after the `input`. When the user search something, this `div` fill by `html` so his `height` is change and he "push" all the rest content away.

**The solution**

You need to add this `css` to yours.

```css
#livesearch {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
}
```

The white `background` is for the content will be not shown behind the search result `div`.

More about `absolute position` you can read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: My pleasure.. Good luck!